# JavaScript insert div

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to insert a div before the "add div" button. I'm receiving an node not found error with this code:

```
document.getElementById("reg").insertBefore(newField, document.getElementById("op"));
```

But this code works, even though it's not the result I want:

```
document.getElementById("reg").insertBefore(newField, document.getElementById("op").parentNode);
```

Here's the source:

```
<form id="reg">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="sectionHeader">Welcome</div>
    <div id="op1">
      <div class="split25">
        <select></select>
      </div>
      <div class="split25">
        <select></select>
      </div>
      <div class="split50">
        <input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="additional" id="op"><button></div>
  </div>
<form>
```

Why can it access its parent node but not itself?

Comment: If you want to insert it inside `div.section`, why not call `insertBefore` on that element?

Comment: Im not sure I follow.  What I want to happen is onClick, add a new div called op2 before <div class="additional id="op">

Comment: That's a child of `div class="section"` so you should call `insertBefore` of that section div, but you've already got an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insertBefore, the second argument has to be a CHILD of the base object

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode);
```

If existingNode is not a child of parentNode this will fail.  That's what is happening in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with this code:
    document.getElementById("op1").insertBefore(newField, document.getElementById("op"));